# How to add a field of a through model to a Django form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

For my Django project I am trying to create a singular form that allows me to add a row in my Pipeline model and link that row to the Process model through the PipelineProcess model. This is fairly straightforward by using ModelForms IF the PipelineProcess model did not have an extra field (phase). I need to be able to view and add/edit the PipelineProcess.phase field in the same form. Note that the PipelineProcess is a "through model" of the Pipeline and Process model.

models.py

```
class Pipeline(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    process = models.ManyToManyField(Process, through='PipelineProcess') ### NOTE THE USAGE OF THE THROUGH MODEL HERE

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'pipeline'


class Process(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'process'


class PipelineProcess(models.Model):
    pipeline = models.ForeignKey(Pipeline, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=False)
    process = models.ForeignKey(Process, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=False)
    phase = models.CharField(max_length=100) ### THIS FIELD I AM UNABLE TO ACCESS THROUGH A FORM

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'pipeline_process'
```

forms.py

```
class PipelineForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pipeline
        fields = ['name', 'sector', 'phase']
```

This form generates the following error which makes sense:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (phase) specified for Pipeline
```

I have tried looking up examples of other people but none of which are useful to me. Most were far too complicated for me to put into my own project. I am fairly new with Django and web dev in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

class PipelineForm(Forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:

    model = Pipeline
    fields = '__all__'
```

the field "phase" you use in your forms.py is not a field of the "Pipeline" class.
and also you put "ModelForms" instend of "Forms.ModelForm"